# erro de código H10 do servidor Heroku num projeto Spring Boot

Tags: git, spring-boot, heroku

Eu sou novo em colocar projetos no servidor Heroku, eu vi nas vídeos aulas que consegui na internet e o passo á passo estava dando tudo certo, os comando do heroku que tudo mais, quando fiz o deployment do projeto no heroku imediatamente digitei a URL para ver se funcionou, quando menos esperar um erro, eu digitei o comando no heroku para ver o o logs de mensagens para ver o que foi que houve, e me retornou erro de codigo H10 como você podem ver a baixo;

```
2017-06-16T13:11:20.179943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-16T13:11:20.199776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-16T13:14:48.671863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/home" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com
request_id=8d98b1e0-f357-469c-a4a3-a44853b744bd fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:14:49.793531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokua
pp.com request_id=55dd4647-dc26-4a2a-8902-c424d4135237 fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:14:57.646730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com requ
est_id=03aae088-c67c-421c-9963-e4fca4efb42a fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:14:57.829488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokua
pp.com request_id=9a369bd9-3318-41dc-9c79-6629c4d40b38 fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:15:11.725485+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com
 request_id=929713b6-181a-41d6-801c-066a726dfaf7 fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:15:11.902088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokua
pp.com request_id=84a93f65-7892-4207-8f4b-233a8a19fb04 fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:17:21.077246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/home" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com
request_id=05a13753-4a19-418f-8cd7-7afc1f9cd726 fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-06-16T13:17:21.258993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokua
pp.com request_id=9b275540-fb81-4680-bcbd-36b5e459dc88 fwd="177.223.27.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Não consigo entender o que está havendo de errado, eu acredito que o problema não seja o projeto, porque o meu projeto Spring Boot funciona perfeitamente no seu servidor local, porém quando vai rodar no servidor do Heroku dá esse erro.

Eu pesquisei bastante, encontrei links como esse [CLICAR AQUI](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed&usg=ALkJrhh2FsUg9qVSh8s3tdVXcOpRqjQ2PA)

Mas as soluções dadas no links não resolveu o meu problema, já dei um **heroku restart** , **heroku run rake db:migrate** e nada.

Alguém já passou por algum problema semelhante ao meu, preciso muito de ajuda para resolver esse problema.

[Clique aqui](https://github.com/wladyband/arm/tree/master/arm) para ter acesso ao meu projeto no repositório GitHub

A pedido do @Sidon

Eu executei todos esse comandos;

- heroku keys:add
- heroku apps:create wb-arm-wladimir
- git init
- git add .
- heroku git:remote -a wb-arm-wladimir
- heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
- git commit -am "projeto wladimir"
- git push heroku master

E apresentou o mesmo problema, e esse é o log

```
 [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_85e5d5182621018e85ec0dd8ddf4c326/arm/target/arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/br/com/arm/arm/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_85e5d5182621018e85ec0dd8ddf4c326/arm/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/br/com/arm/arm/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 15.801 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-16T16:15:29Z
       [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/328M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 85.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v4
       https://wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

**Preciso salientar que deu o mesmo problema, e fiz tudo de novo do zero, mas não resolveu.**

Comment: Sugestão: Faça login na sua conta heroku, va no dashboard e clique na aplicacao, no lado direito vc vai ver os builds, clique em `view build log`, pelo menos no meu caso, sempre acho melhor a consulta nesse log.
Outra coisa que as vezes faço e sempre dá certo é simplesmente deletar a app no heroku  e "reconstrui-la" com atenção nos detalhes. Para deleta-la vá em settings.

Comment: vou fazer isso agora e te passo o passo á passo do que eu fiz em comandos git, só um minuto

Comment: Dá uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Dificil avaliar sem conhecer o contexto completo. O primeiro log apresenta erro mas esse segundo diz q o build foi construido com sucesso. Seu ambiente é linux ou windows? se for linux tente o comando : `heroku logs --tail -a <sua app> | grep 'error\|failed'`ou seu equivalente no windows.

Comment: O primeiro log foi retirado do comando heroku logs --tail, esse comando serve para acompanhar o logs do servidor Heroku no pc local. O segundo log mostra logs da View Build Log visto no proprío site do heroku como você mesmo sugerio de verificar. Meu ambiente é o Windows. Eu sugiro que você baixe o meu projeto do GitHub e tente realizar o deployment direto do seu computador para o servidor Heroku de sua conta Heroku para tira possíveis dúvidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizei um fork do seu repositório para realizar alguns testes, o que vi ao tentar subir a aplicação foi uma Exception:

> 2017-06-16T17:48:37.460780+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   org.postgresql.Drive

Verifiquei seu código mais a fundo e via que no seu `application.properties` o trecho `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` está incorreto

Sua versão:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Drive
```

Versão correta:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Por conta do nome incorreto, o spring não conseguiu localizar a classe:

> Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Drive

Comment: Nossa mano, o que uma simples letra faz a diferença, muito obrigado, valeu mesmo.

Comment: Costumo ter esse tipo de problema com o thymeleaf, ele costuma só avisar quando você acessa a página com erro

Comment: Isso não era para acontecer, mas fazer o que? Estou vendo a possibilidade de estudar Angular JS, pra aprender sozinho é muito ruim pra mim, mas estou esperando o próximo mês para me livrar do Thymeleaf. Esse projeto vai servir como portfólio para eu conseguir futuras entrevistas de trabalho. :)